# Why does gulp-watch ignore glob-parameter?

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

Given the following `gulpfile.js` (simplified), why does gulp-watch not exclude the `mongoData`-folder?

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  paths = {
    js: ['*.js', 'test/**/*.js', '!test/coverage/**', '!bower_components/**', '!packages/**/node_modules/**', '!packages/contrib/**/*.js', '!packages/contrib/**/node_modules/**', '!packages/core/**/*.js', '!packages/core/public/assets/lib/**/*.js']
  };

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch([paths.js, '!mongoData/**/*.*']).on('change', plugins.livereload.changed);
});
```

I also tried adding `!mongoData/**/*.*` in `paths.js` without success.

Answer (score 0):

gulp.watch expects an array of globs as the first parameter, you should write like this:

```
gulp.watch(paths.js.concat(['!mongoData/**/*.*']))
```

Comment: did not fix the problem :(

Comment: According to the documentation https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob you, probably, forgot the brackets: `'!(mongoData)/**/*.*'`

Comment: tried that and still not working. I temporarily fixed the problem by moving the `mongoData` folder outside the scope of gulp